# Performing Long-Term Actions in the Background Swift 3

Tags: swift, core-bluetooth

I have an app that uses Corebluetooth and uses its Background services. I need also long-term CoreBluetooth action so I need to implement State preservation and restoration. I followed Apple document the link at the below https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html also watched WWDC 2013 presentation video link below,
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/703/
 First of all, the sources are in Objective C and I am not familiar with that, I tried to convert them in swift3.

Then, I defined CBCentralManager with restoration identifier shown below,

`self.myCentralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: [CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey: "myCentralManager"])`

Then, added delegate method something in the below,

```
func centralManager( willRestoreState dict: [String : AnyObject]) {
        let peripherals: [CBPeripheral] = dict[CBCentralManagerRestoredStatePeripheralsKey] as! [CBPeripheral]
        for peripheral in peripherals {
            self.peripherals.append(peripheral)
            peripheral.delegate = self
        }
    }
```

Finally did didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method in AppDelegate,

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {

        if let peripheralManagerIdentifiers: [String] = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.bluetoothCentrals] as? [String]{
            for identifier in peripheralManagerIdentifiers{
                if (identifier == "myCentralManager"){

                }
            }
        }

        return true
    }
```

When I debug, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method called, the parameter launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.bluetoothCentrals] is nil I think because of first time I created the app, then got error when defining CBCentralManager with restoration identifier the error is "reason: ' has provided a restore identifier but the delegate doesn't implement the centralManager:willRestoreState: method'"

I'm totally confused, thank you for any help,

Best regards,

Comment: I found a document at below, solved my problem,
 https://www.cloudcity.io/blog/2016/09/14/zero-to-ble-on-ios--part-three/
In my scenario I just used scanForPeripherals func in willRestoreState, works great!